# element.css('filter') returns undefined in jQuery 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, filter

Assume you have the following style (filter or -ms-filter, it doesn't matter):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #someID {
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFFFFF, endColorstr=#ECECEC)";
    }
</style>
```

In jQuery 1.7 the following script worked to read IE filter properties...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        alert($('#someID').css('filter'));
    });
</script>
```

Now in jQuery 1.8+ this returns undefined. a) Is this a bug in jQuery 1.8? b) Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/MbULY/, even on jquery 1.7.2 says none.

Comment: Thats what I was about to say, the thing is is says "none" and not "undefined".

Comment: In all other browsers, aside from IE, it should say none. In IE it should return the property. It actually still works in IE8 with jQuery 1.8+ so I've submitted a bug to jQuery core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it in jQuery either, but I found a way to do it in plain javascript (Will only work for IE, you will need to catch it so other browsers don't fail).

```
var _someID = document.getElementById('someID');
var someIdGradientFilter = _someID.filters.item('DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient');
alert("startColorstr: " + someIdGradientFilter.startColorstr + "\nendColorstr: " + someIdGradientFilter.endColorstr);
```

Comment: Thank you, this will do nicely.